# Factorial program with STATIC INT

Tags: c, recursion, factorial

how this program behaves,

```
fact(static int n)
{
  int f=1;
  if(n<=1) return 1;
  else
  {
   f=n*fact(n-1);
   return f;
  }
}
```

how the function calls and return values depends on n and why final output is 1.

Comment: If, perchance, this is embedded C code, `static` means the parameter is allocated globally; thus, the function is not re-entrant (cannot recurse safely).

Comment: You have to return f in both conditions ,but after recursive calling of that function you finally return 1 so the final output is 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some embedded C compilers support `static` as a parameter specifier as a non-standard extension. For these compilers, `static` means a parameter that is globally allocated (generally, this is done to save stack space, which can be very limited on an embedded platform).

In this case, the presence of a `static` parameter means the function is not re-entrant (cannot recurse safely). A globally allocated `n` would simply change on every call until the final call `fact(1)`; as the recursion unwinds, every returning call will multiply `n` (now equal to 1) into the result, so the net effect is that a bunch of 1s are multiplied together to produce the final result.

Answer (score 2):

Storage class specifiers (except `register`) are not allowed in function parameter declaration. Your program is not a valid C program.

To make it valid, change:

```
fact(static int n)
```

to

```
int fact(int n)
```

Note that MPLAB C18 compiler allows `static` specifier to function parameters as a compiler extension. From [MPLAB C18 user guide](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/51288f.pdf):

> 2.3.2 static Function Arguments
>
> Function parameters can have storage class auto or static. An auto parameter is
>   placed on the software stack, enabling reentrancy. A static parameter is allocated globally, enabling direct access for generally smaller code. static parameters are valid only when the compiler is operating in Non-Extended mode (see Section 1.2.5 “Selecting the Mode”).